# Question re ACML_demo rosout messages

Tags: ros, messages, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I am fairly new to ROS, so forgive a rookie question. When I run amcl_demo.launch and view the output, I can see info such as "goal reached" and "got new plan", and I would like to publish these to a rostopic. Trouble is, I can't seem to find which file these info messages are originating from. I checked through the amcl_demo.launch file, the amcl.launch.xlm, etc. but can't find where the info logging is coming from. Any help would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280464/question-re-acml_demo-rosout-messages/) by [g-bot](https://answers.ros.org/users/33384/g-bot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-01-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-22**:
I'm not sure of how much use it is, but those messages are "log messages", and are emitted by `move_base` itself. Specifically: [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/e538b4f4624c7f757d4868e5200ba8f8904a0d94/move_base/src/move_base.cpp#L874).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-22**:
It might be better / less invasive to subscribe to the action topic(s) that `move_base` listens to. You should be able to derive goal status from that.

**Comment by [g-bot](https://answers.ros.org/users/33384/g-bot/) on 2018-01-22**:
Thanks for the info. I took a look for move_base.cpp, and I can't seem to find it. I found folders move_base_msg, etc. but not move_base.cpp. (I also searched for all .cpp files)  Could it be called something else in my distro? I am run indigo (source installation) with a turtlebot 1 (create, kinect

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-22**:
If you installed things using `apt` (or `apt-get`) you will not find the source code on your system. That is expected.

You'll have to build the navigation stack from source to edit it.

But again: I would look at the [action server](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib) topics to get at this info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Those messages come through the rosconsole logging system: http://wiki.ros.org/rosconsole

The messages are already published on the `rosout` topic and can be viewed in [rqt_console](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_console) and other similar tools.

A full overview of the logging system can be found here: http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Logging

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [g-bot](https://answers.ros.org/users/33384/g-bot/) on 2018-01-22**:
Hi, I can see that they are being published on rosout, but I am interested in having them published to a new topic that I've created as well. I don't want to have to parse all of the information from rosout just to grab these pieces of info.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-22**:
@g-bot: can you clarify what the problem is with looking at the actionlib Goal, Status and Result topics? Those get you the same info and don't seem to require any modification of `move_base` code.